# invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to read a simple text file into R using the following code:

> 8307=read.table("8307.txt")

But it gives me the error: 
Error in 8307 = read.table("8307.txt") :invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment.

You can see the file I'm trying to read here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6aa61fa8va5cdtr/8307.txt?dl=0

I don't understand why its not accepting such a simple command. I'm not trying to do anything complicated. I've tries using Fill=TRUE, row.names=NULL,header=FALSE, basically everything I can think of.

I'm using a mac, if that has any bearing?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: From `?make.names`: _A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and the dot or underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot not followed by a number._

Comment: You are not under any obligation to call your data `8307`. Name it whatever you want as long as it complies with the rules described by @lukeA.

Answer (score 6):

Problem is with your basics of R knowledge

You cannot name your parameter starting with number. And if you want to start it try this

```
`8307` = read.table("8307.txt")
```

Comment: Although that does indeed work I would really avoid having a variable named 8307....